# Unwanted Header in Excel Output of Cognos 11 Reports

Tags: excel, cognos

I was wondering if anyone else is experiencing the same problem. We recently upgraded from Cognos 10.2 to Cognos 11 and now we are experiencing the issue that an extra row is added automatically top the of reports in the Excel output.

It seems to be an automatic page number, but this is not needed or desired by my customer for Excel reports.

This is even happening to me in blank reports with no template specified.

I would like to know if this is a bug, or if there is a setting somewhere that one could change?

Answer (score 0):

Cognos will only do this if you are working in design mode. Try saving the report, and running it outside of design mode.